# "Filename" vs "Filename-git"

Tags: bash, arch-linux, filenames, git, autocomplete

What is the meaning of files that end in -git? For example, I searched in a Terminal for "xcb-imdkit" then pressed tab. xcb-imdkit comes up, as well as "xcb-imdkit-git".

Answer (score 3):

In Arch, it is quite common to see AUR packages of a project’s releases alongside packages of regular snapshots the same project. These snapshot packages are commonly suffixed with `-git` (at least, when they involve snapshots of a git repository). In some cases, typically when the project doesn’t publish releases, there is no corresponding non-`-git` package.

[`xcd-imdkit-git`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xcb-imdkit-git/) is an instance of this pattern: it packages snapshots of the project’s git repository, [which doesn’t have any formal release](https://github.com/wengxt/xcb-imdkit).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a more solid convention here than "it probably has something with Git to do".

[Searching for Debian packages which contain matches](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=-git&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) brings up files for which I can observe the following rough patterns;

- Some version control tools have modules or components which are specific to `git`; you would expect to find similar modules with suffices like `-svn` or `-hg` or `-cvs` for other version control systems;
- Some files or packages are marked as originating from the upstream project's Git repository by using this naming convention (near as I can tell, `xcb-imdkit-git` is an example of this;
- Some tools simply are named so as to convey that they somehow operate on a Git repository or allow you to somehow interface to Git;

  - As a special case of this, some projects contain hook scripts which are named so as to suggest their intended use in a particular Git hook.